Running utilities into bomb shelter / bunker
In peace and disaster time, bomb shelters are utilised for living spaces. Hence, what are some considerations for drilling through the reinforced walls to run utilities such as water, petrol, electricity, sewage lines to the septic or municipal sewer and even fibre Internet into the bunker that has not been included in the design while preserving the integrity of the fortification?
Also, what drill equipment is needed to cut through such reinforcement?
To be sure, this is a high-end bunker similar to the ones used by the military.

Lots of bits and time. Consider what you want to keep out (or in) and how introducing pipes, wires, etc affects that.

What utilities do you expect to be functional during/after a situation that requires the use of the bunker? Also, consider what use "unfriendlies" might make of such connections if they exist.

@DaveTweed dual use tech. Peace time it's expected to be connected to the grid, but not during a disaster or emergency.

A self contained bunker would have reservoirs / storage compartment, processing units  within the bunker.

To minimize damage to the concrete/material surrounding any proposed holes, and depending on the thickness and nature of the material being drilling through, diamond saws or drill bits would best be used; particularly bits or saws that produce core of the drilled material. You need to minimize cracking of the wall around such holes as this will weaken the walls. Diamond bits/saws are good for this as diamond drills do not have a hammering/percussive component in there function; they use rotation. Avoid drills that are rotatory percussive - such drills use button, cross or chisel bits.
Do not make a hole larger than it needs to be.
Ideally, it would better to put the holes in the walls/ceiling as the walls/ceiling are being constructed and to leave the holes open using a form of conduit, or in the case of a pipe, a section of pipe with the ability to connect to the pipes inside and outside and provide an effective seal, using something like flange of screw fittings, as deemed appropriate for your application.
The other thing to consider is how to seal the holes once cables or pipes have been placed in them. This will be influenced by what adverse events you want the bunker to protect against: radiation, toxic gases, heat and flames from an intense wild fire, water inundation and flooding, etc.

You use off-the-shelf components for industrial explosion-proof walls like in flour mills, armories, bomb bunkers, etc. Most will be air-gapped as well if you are serious about this stuff. Run all power through a motor-generator set after the switchgear and have the diesel generator, switchgear, fuel, and normal HVAC, in a soft support building. Keep the batteries, water, ESA vault, MG set, and filters in the bomb shelter.
https://www.needco.com/product/category/US_150311000000/explosion-proof-enclosures
https://www.roxtec.com/us/knowledge-library/sealing-solutions/conduit-applications/?gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpZWzBhC0ARIsACvjWRMy5SuY4DVUaHsBFj6eIAPuirkM_-qXckWZiGKOq1zGtTf3QGXEfnIaAuESEALw_wcB
